# "Are your messages built?" error from echoing that message (Groovy)

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, message, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone,

I've followed the steps closely defined [here](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt)
to create a custom message, editting my CMakeLists.txt, my package.xml, and my msg/data_logger_measurement.msg to create a new message.

I've been able to display the data with "rostopic echo /data_logger_measurement" in the past; however, now that I've rosbagged the data to revisit it a few weeks later, I cannot "rostopic echo /data_logger_measurement" when I'm playing a rosbag.

Instead, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [external_sensor_interface/data_logger_measurement]. Are your messages built?
```

The only changes that I can remember making are updating ROS when I performed a software update on Ubuntu.

Does anyone have any possible leads?  (I may have made a few other changes in the past few weeks to ROS, but I cannot currently remember them.)

Thanks very much in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62430/%22are-your-messages-built?%22-error-from-echoing-that-message-(groovy)/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-09**:
Can you roscd to your package from that shell? If not, your ROS environment is not set up correctly.

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-05-09**:
Ah, this has got to be the problem.  roscd won't tab-complete to that package.  Under the old flavor, I could just change my package path to fix this.  How do I resolve this in the Groovy?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-09**:
There are several ways. The recommended approach is here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Overlays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this will help you or not but I figured I might as well add...

I was having this same problem a couple of weeks back and here is what I learned:

1. Make sure that you have a package called "external_sensor_interface" that contains a msg directory with your "data_logger_measurement" msg defined there. This package should be on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (see http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables). Changing it should look something like...

   echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/path/to/your/project/":$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
2. Build your messages - You need to edit your CMakeLists file (and you indicated that you already did this..) and rebuild your project. **NOTE:** This is where I was having problems - specifically with catkin. I switched my entire project to use rosbuild and I had smooth sailing from that point forward.

If all that worked correctly, you should be able to do,

```
rosmsg show data_logger_measurement
```

which will display your message details...From there you should be good to go.

---

Originally posted by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) with karma: 198 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-05-09**:
Oops!  I forgot to source my setup.sh script in the devel folder.  Afterwards, my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH points to the right directory and the ROSBAG that I wanted to play will now display the data from data_logger_measurement.  Thanks everyone!

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-01**:
I did the #1. As for the #2 it does not work, but then again it does not work either for some messages that work correctly!